How to resolve error_subcode 1363019 when publishing video to Facebook Page via Graph API
I'm trying to upload a video to af Facebook Page following this Graph API documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/publishing
I have been able to upload the video and received a video handle in response (step 2).
However, no matter what I try, when doing the final "publish" step (step 3), I get this response:
{
    "error": {
        "message": "There was a problem uploading your video file. Please try again with another file.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 6000,
        "error_data": {
            "error": null
        },
        "error_subcode": 1363019,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "Video wasn't uploaded",
        "error_user_msg": "There was a problem with uploading your video. Please wait a few minutes and try again.",
        "fbtrace_id": "AMa9zbs8h3b4omv5wRSfTsf"
    }
}

Things I've tried:

Making POST request via Facebook Javascript SDK
Making POST request via axios
Making POST request via axios via CORS proxy
Making POST request via the Graph API Explorer
Making POST request from a vercel.app host rather than localhost
Using both graph.facebook.com and graph-video.facebook.com
Posting a variety of video file types and sizes
⠀
Every time, exactly the same response (fbtrace_id changes)

Needless to say, the error message isn't giving me enough information to find the cause of the problem (and waiting a few minutes and trying again later doesn't help).
The request that is being made (via Javascript SDK) is:
curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/<PAGE_ID>/videos?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'origin: https://localhost:3000' \
  -H 'priority: u=1, i' \
  -H 'referer: https://localhost:3000/' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Not/A)Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="126", "Google Chrome";v="126"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: cross-site' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --data-raw $'description=Victoria\'s%20nurses%20and%20midwives%20have%20voted%20down%20a%20proposed%2023%25%20pay%20rise%20over%20four%20years%2C%20citing%20uncertainty%20and%20a%20desire%20for%20better%20conditions.&fbuploader_video_file_chunk=<VERY_LONG_VIDEO_HANDLE>&method=post&pretty=0&sdk=joey&suppress_http_code=1&title=Nurses%20Reject%20Offer'

I suspect the problem has to do with permissions and the Facebook app configuration. I tried to post just a regular Page Post and that was successful. The successful Page Post request was:
curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/<PAGE_ID>/feed?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'origin: https://localhost:3000' \
  -H 'priority: u=1, i' \
  -H 'referer: https://localhost:3000/' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Not/A)Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="126", "Google Chrome";v="126"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: cross-site' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --data-raw 'message=Nurses%20Reject%20Offer&method=post&pretty=0&sdk=joey&suppress_http_code=1'

Other contextual information

The Facebook App has not undergone App Review yet, but the User is connected to the Facebook App, so that shouldn't be a problem
The User has admin access to the test Page
“Business Verification” is complete
developers.facebook.com is saying we can’t apply for Access Verification because we don’t need Access Verification.
App Type is ‘business’ and App Mode is ‘development’
Based on the user access token and the page access token, the permissions are: (same for both)

email
publish_video
pages_show_list
pages_read_engagement
pages_read_user_content
pages_manage_posts
pages_manage_engagement


Screenshot of Facebook App login configuration:

login variation: general
access token: User access token
permissions: pages_show_list, publish_video, pages_manage_posts, email, pages_read_management, pages_manage_engagement


Another possible clue: After uploading the video (step 2) and receiving a video handle in response, I can't see the uploaded video anywhere. I can't see it on any Facebook page (not listed on user's personal page, the business page, as 'cross postable' content in the Creator Studio etc) and when I make a  Graph API request for the user's videos, I get an empty array in response. Maybe uploaded videos remain invisible until they are published at least once? Or maybe there's a problem with the upload, despite the successful response from the HTTP request?
Facebook does not provide a way to communicate with them about this apart from posting to community forums (no dev support, can’t even raise bug tickets). This problem is also posted at [ Video API ] error_subcode: [...] when publishing video - Developer Community Forum - Meta for Developers, but raising here on S.O. because no response on the other one.

